# Assigning a field value from firestore to variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, textfield

I am trying to get four text field values from a specific firestore document, assign them to four different variables and use them in the build context.

This is what I have been trying to do for just one field value:

```
  class PackageScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<PackageScanPage> createState() => _PackageScanPageState();
}
  class _PackageScanPageState extends State<PackageScanPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final textFieldValue = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    var _message;

    _fetchData() async{
      _firestore.collection("groceries").document('$textFieldValue').get().then((value) {
        setState(() {
          _message = value.data['name'];
        });
      });
    }
  return Container(
    child: Text(_message.toString())
   ),
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'get four text field values from a specific firestore document, assign them to four different variables'

if you are trying to pass the text field value from the app to firebase then I got you

```
TextField(
                          onSubmitted: (value) async {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
                                (Transaction myTransaction) async {
                              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('example')
                                  .doc('example')
                                  .update({'something': value});
                            }
```